# Proving Altitudes of Triangle can never form a Triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

Prove that Altitudes of Triangle can never form a Triangle

My try: we have altitudes proportional to reciprocals of sides of given triangle

Let $a,b,c$ are sides we have

$$a+b \gt c $$

$$b+c \gt a$$ and $$c+a \gt b$$

Now if $\frac{1}{a}$, $\frac{1}{b}$ and $\frac{1}{c}$ are sides of another Triangle  we need to show that

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$ Can never be Greater than $\frac{1}{c}$

Any hint?

Comment: Don't the altitudes of an equilateral triangle form another equilateral triangle?

Comment: Is this true? In an equilateral triangle, the altitudes are all of the same length, therefore trivially form a triangle.

Comment: I guess this depends on what you are allowed to do with the altitudes. Are you allowed to move them around? If so, are you allowed to rotate them or just translate them?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \geq b \geq c$ be the sides of a triangle. If $p,q,r$ are the altitudes of the triangle incident at $a,b,c$ respectively, then $$
\frac 12 ap = \frac 12 bq = \frac 12 cr = \Delta,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle formed by $a,b,c$. As a consequence, $$
p:q:r = \frac{1}{a} : \frac 1b : \frac 1c.
$$
Note that, by scaling a triangle if necessary, we see that $p,q,r$ form a triangle if and only if $\frac 1a,\frac 1b$ and $\frac 1c$ do.

Observe that $\frac 1a \leq \frac 1b \leq \frac 1c$. Therefore, the three quantities can be the sides of a triangle if and only if $\frac 1c < \frac 1b + \frac 1a$, which happens if and only if $c(a+b) > ab$.

Which means that there may be triangles for which the altitudes do actually form a triangle, for example if $a=b=c$, and there are examples where triangles are not formed e.g. if $c(a+b) \leq ab$. You can check that $3,3,1$ is a triangle, whose altitudes would not form a triangle since $1(3+3) = 6$ while $3 \times 3= 9$.

Comment: 3,3,1 they won't form a triangle; but they do for your example.

Comment: You say triangles are not formed if c(a+b)<=ab.  But your example has c(a+b)>ab.

Answer (score 1):

The altitudes of $\triangle ABC$ can form a triangle **if and only if**

> $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}>2\max\left(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}\right)$$

where $a,b,c$ are the sides of $\triangle ABC.$

Comment: Do you have a proof ?

Answer (score 1):

The altitudes can form a triangle for some but not all triangles $ABC$.

**I.** In isosceles triangle $ABC$, with altitudes $AD$, $BE$, $CF$, let $AC=2BC$.[image: altitudes in isosceles triangle]

Since$$\triangle ADC\sim\triangle BEC$$then$$\frac{AD}{BE}=\frac{AC}{BC}$$hence$$AD=2BE$$And since $BE=CF$, then $$AD=BE+CF$$and altitudes $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ cannot form a triangle when $\cos \angle ACB=\frac{DC}{AC}=.25$, that is for$$\angle ACB\ge\arccos .25=75.52^o$$But if $AC<2BC$, that is if $\angle ACB<75.52^O$, then since$$AD<2BE=BE+CF$$the three altitudes can form a triangle.

**II.** The altitudes of a right triangle can form a triangle only if the least angle is not much less than $30^o$.

In triangle $ABC$ with right angle at $C$, suppose $BC>AC$, and hence the least angle is at $B$. Points $E$, $D$ are coincident with $C$. Thus the altitudes can form a triangle only if$$AD+CF>BE$$[image: altitudes in right triangle]

Constructing $FG\parallel CB$ and $\angle CBG=\angle FCB$, draw circle with radius $BG=CF$ making $BH=CF$. And let $AD$ be such that $AD=DH$. Then$$AD+CF=BE$$and the three altitudes cannot form a triangle. With $J$ the midpoint of $AB$, evidently $$AD<\frac12AB$$and hence$$\angle ABC<30^o$$

Then keeping $BD$ fixed it is clear that if we decrease $AD$, thereby also decreasing $CF$, then$$AD+CF<BE$$ and again the altitudes cannot form a triangle. But if instead we increase $AD$, hence also increasing $CF$, then$$AD+CF>BE$$and the altitudes can form a triangle. And they will continue to form a triangle until $AD$ has to $BE$ the ratio which $BE$ formerly had to $AD$, i.e. until the angles at $A$ and $B$ are the reverse of what they are in the figure. But if $AD$ is made greater still, the altitudes will no longer form a triangle.

Thus the altitudes of a right triangle can form a triangle if the complementary acute angles are between slightly greater than $60^o$, and slightly less than $30^o$.

It seems clear from just these two types of cases, that the altitudes of a triangle can form a triangle neither always nor never, but only under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for a triangle is
$c(a+b) > ab$.

For the 3-4-5 triangle,
this is
$5(3+4) > 3\cdot 4$
which is true.

So the altitudes do form a triangle
in this case.

Note that you can write
the condition as

$\begin{array}\\
0
&\gt ab-c(a+b)\\
&= ab-c(a+b)+c^2-c^2\\
&= (a-c)(b-c)-c^2\\
\text{or}\\
c^2
&\gt (a-c)(b-c)\\
&= (c-a)(c-b)\\
\end{array}
$

This is true if
$c$ is the largest side
of the triangle,
so it is always true.

Therefore,
the altitudes can
*always* form a triangle.

Comment: In the condition $c(a+b)>ab$, isn't $c$ supposed to be the smallest side of the triangle? If so, then it doesn't follow that $c^2>(c-a)(c-b)$.

Comment: Largest side for my calculation.

Comment: But then the condition becomes $bc<a(b+c)$, and you get $a^2>(a-b)(a-c)$, which isn't always true.